# what is the best alternative to nested ternaries?

Tags: javascript, nested

I am looking for the best way to do nested ternaries. 
here is the code:

```
<div style={{overflowY: "auto", overflowX: "hidden", maxHeight: "165px"}}>
    {
        this.props.displayGenericAlerts && this.props.genericAlerts.length > 0 ?
            this.props.genericAlerts.map((alert, index) => <AlertPanel key={index} alert={alert} index={index} />) :
            this.state.alerts.result && this.state.alerts.result.length > 0 ?
                this.state.alerts.result.map((alert, index) => <AlertPanel key={index} alert={alert} index={index} />) :
                !alertResource.isError() && !alertResource.isLoading() && this.state.accountAlert ?
                    alertResource.get("content").map((alert, index) => <AlertPanel key={index} alert={alert.toJS()} index={index} />) :
                    <span>No Alerts Found</span>
    }
</div>
```

I would be appreciate any help

Comment: What do you mean with "best"? Is there something wrong with your current code? In the question title you ask for an alternative, and in the question body you ask for a way to "do" them. Not sure what you are after...

Comment: Either you nest them or you write it with if/else if/else.... not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 (simple):** You can move the code to a method:

```
getAlerts() {
    if (this.props.displayGenericAlerts && this.props.genericAlerts.length > 0) {
        return this.props.genericAlerts.map((alert, index) => <AlertPanel key={index} alert={alert} index={index} />);
    } else if (this.state.alerts.result && this.state.alerts.result.length > 0) {
        return this.state.alerts.result.map((alert, index) => <AlertPanel key={index} alert={alert} index={index} />);
    } else if (!alertResource.isError() && !alertResource.isLoading() && this.state.accountAlert) {
        return alertResource.get("content").map((alert, index) => <AlertPanel key={index} alert={alert.toJS()} index={index} />);
    } else {
        return <span>No Alerts Found</span>
    }
}
```

**Option 2 (fancy):** There is a Babel plugin (currently at stage 0, play with it [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDAzAbgFAdJWECWAXgKZIwAmIMA3hjDPgGYAUCAfDAIwAMAlDXXowA5ACN8Ac2GZ6AXxjEANhFJMYrGBwCs_WkJEBbYuXwBXA9MHylKgfuEQDAQ0WLLcjLMzZwEEIuIAOkUQCWYCEl40IA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=stage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)) that implements `do-expressions` that makes it possible to write an `if/else` chain as an expression, so you directly use it with JSX. [babel-plugin-transform-do-expressions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-do-expressions):

```
<div>
  {do {
    if (cond2) {
      value1;
    } else if (cond2) {
      value2; 
    } else {
      value3;
    }
  }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I do not really want to use "else if " here.

Comment: @SamiraArabgol why? added a second option.

Comment: @SamiraArabgol —`else if` is lovely. It is nice and readable. Get over your desire to avoid it.